# Easiest & Most Efficient Way to Making a Bitmap Using For Loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, bitmap, bitmapimage

I've been stuck on this for awhile, I eventually gave up but can anyone lead me in the correct direction. Also side note, I need the final result to have alpha.

```
static std::unique_ptr<unsigned char [ ]> ImageData;

    if ( !ImageData) {
        ImageData = std::make_unique<unsigned char [ ]>( Width* Height);

        for ( int x = 0; i < Width; x++) {
            for ( int y = 0; y < Height; y++ ) {
                float Red = 128, Green = 128, Blue = 255, Alpha = 255;
                // some cool math to determine color based off x/y.
                // . . .
                const unsigned char a[] = { Red, Green, Blue, Alpha };
                *reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ImageData.get() + x + y * Height) = *a;
            };    
        };
    };
```

The image generated is completely trash and unusable, it's just random corruption everywhere.

Comment: The expression `*a` is equal to `a[0]`. That is, you only assign the `Red` value to each byte in the bitmap.

Comment: You want an array of [`RGBQUAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagrgbquad) (if you don't have Windows headers, make your own structure)

Answer (score 1):

1. **You question is unclear as you did not specify pixel format**

   so what is the pixelformat `8/15/16/24/32` bpp ? which order rgab / bgra ?
2. **why `const char` ?**

   that would not change with position !!! and also as **Some programmer dude** suggested `*a` will copy just the first `BYTE` so the rest of the channels are unitialized hence garbage output.
3. **image data is `char`?**

   that is OK but then the pointer arithmetics is 8 bit not 32 bit !!!
4. **`for(x...)` loop has `i` inside that is most likely a thypo**
5. **why `float` channels?**

   that only leads to casting problems ...

So if I put all together your code is not working at all as expected. To remedy it and  assuming the rest of code (visualization) is OK and the pixel format is 32bpp I would change your code to this:

```cpp
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned __int32 DWORD;
static std::unique_ptr<unsigned char [ ]> ImageData;
const int _r=0; // here change the RGB/BGR order
const int _g=1;
const int _b=2;
const int _a=3;
if ( !ImageData)
  {
  ImageData = std::make_unique<unsigned char [ ]>( Width* Height*4);
  int x,y,a;
  BYTE db[4];
  DWORD *dd=(DWORD*)(void*)db;
  DWORD *p=reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(ImageData.get());
  for (a=0,y=0;y<Height;y++) 
   for (   x=0;x<Width;x++,a++)
     {
     // some cool math to determine color based on x,y.
     db[_r]=x;
     db[_g]=y;
     db[_b]=x+y;
     db[_a]=128;
     // copy pixel
     p[a]=*dd;
     }
  }
```

Hope I did the pointer cast OK as I do not use the `std::unique_ptr`. Also I coded it directly in SO/SE editor so there might be hidden minor syntax errors or thypos.